# How do I change air wing composition on existing carriers?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4, man-the-guns

When constructing aircraft carriers it is possible to assign the number and types of aircraft (fighter, dive bomber, torpedo bomber) to a carrier.

How can I change the air wing composition once a carrier is constructed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the buttons in the screenshot
[image]

[image]